# git log ignores options like --stat / -p / --name-only

Tags: git

I'm on a Windows machine and have git 2.39,
Git log seems to work in its basic form, but when I try to use options like

```
git log -p
git log --stat
git log --name-only
```

It looks like regular git log! like the options are ignored

This happens both on git-bash and cmd

Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: If the view only has merge commits in it, you may not see the details. (I think you can simulate this by also using `--merges`.) I assume you're seeing this for commits with changes too though...

Comment: do add `--graph`, you will at least have a view of how commits are related one to another -- e.g : if your history is full of merges or if you have a regular straight line of commits.

Comment: As said by TTT: by default git log will not show details or patch or diff related info for merge commits. You may try one of the [diff-merges options](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#Documentation/git-log.txt---diff-mergesoffnoneonfirst-parent1separatemcombinedcdense-combinedccremerger) of git log, like `-c` or `--cc`. Do also check the diff between two commits  : `git diff a b`, to confirm whether they are different or have indeed the same content.

Comment: What's the output from `type -a git`? Does `git show --oneline` work as-expected? I'm thinking there may be a `git.bat` somewhere in the path that's not passing arguments properly.